# Group values in specific order

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list of data that I need to order and group in a specific order. Find below the data that I'm working with:

```
 trackId  |  sectionId  |  lineId
----------------------------------
 2        |  5          |  210
 1        |  1193       |  210
 1        |  1192       |  210
 1        |  1191       |  210
 1        |  987        |  360
 1        |  988        |  360
 2        |  986        |  360
 1        |  985        |  360
 1        |  1189       |  360
```

I need to find a way to group this data by `lineId` and `trackId`, but only in the order they come. So I can't group 4x trackId 1 and lineId 360.

This is the result I need:

```
lineId = 210, trackId = 2, sectionId = 5
lineId = 210, trackId = 1, sectionId = 1193, 1192, 1191
**lineId = 360, trackId = 1, sectionId = 987, 988**
lineId = 360, trackId = 2, sectionId = 986
**lineId = 360, trackId = 1, sectionId = 985, 1189**
```

Notice how a normal `.GroupBy(g => new { g.lineId, g.trackId })` would group both lineId 360 and trackId 1 into 1 group, while in fact I need two groups.

This is the result I currently get (which is wrong):

```
lineId = 210, trackId = 2, sectionId = 5
lineId = 210, trackId = 1, sectionId = 1193, 1192, 1191
**lineId = 360, trackId = 1, sectionId = 987, 988, 985, 1189**
lineId = 360, trackId = 2, sectionId = 986
```

So, how exactly do I pull this off? I guess I could add some ifs and elses to make it happen, but I'm hoping for some synthetic sugar.

Comment: I don't understand why somebody downvoted. I'd be more helpful if you atleast gave some feedback about it.

Comment: Loop. Use an accumulator as you go. Reset when you hit a new `trackId`.

Comment: if each group of 2 same track id has one unique id e.g track id with section id 1193, 1192 has unique id of let's assume '1'  and like wise and then you group by lineid, unique id it will work. but how you get that unique id's is upon you. You can use temp table make some logic code and insert the data with unique id in that temp table. finally call the temp table with group by tag

Comment: You're probably downvoted because you didn't provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (as in code). Also, I don't see how Splenda would help here.

Comment: @Crowcoder Yea this currently seemed like the best solution, but was really hoping for some synthetic c# magic :)

Comment: @KennethK. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar ;) (unless you knew what it ment. In that case, nevermind)

Comment: I'd guess downvotes are because you only showed the simplest most trivial attempt to do it and nothing more..

Comment: @JorisDecraecker Yes, I knew what he meant ;)

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing so using linq would be:

```
var list = data.Select((item, index) => (item, index));
var group = 1;
var result = (from prev in list
              join curr in list on prev.index + 1 equals curr.index into j
              from curr in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select (prev.item, curr.item.trackId == prev.item.trackId && curr.item.lineId == prev.item.lineId ? @group : @group++) into s
              group s.item.sectionId by (s.Item2, s.item.trackId, s.item.lineId) into g
              select new { g.Key.trackId, g.Key.lineId, sectionIds = g.ToList() }).ToList();
```

Basically it joins each item with its following item and gives a grouping number if the two fields match. Afterwards group by the fields and the grouping sequence as needed.

---

For ease I use Named Tuples and initialized the data like this:

```
var data = new List<(int trackId, int sectionId, int lineId)>
{
    (2, 5, 210),
    (1, 1193, 210),
    (1, 1192, 210),
    (1, 1191, 210),
    (1, 987, 360),
    (1, 988, 360),
    (2, 986, 360),
    (1, 986, 360),
    (1, 1189, 360),
};
```

Comment: For readability, I'd almost just rather add another property to the Tuple (in your case) using a `do/while` and using the native `GroupBy` on that.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use .ThenBy()
`.GroupBy(g => g.lineId).ThenBy(x => x.trackId)`

Comment: That's not how you group by multiple things.

Comment: Nice try though, but indeed ThenBy only works on `IOrderedEnumerable` objects, so you can't use it on a `GroupBy()`, but only on an `OrderBy()`